# Re-positioning of buttons in landscape mode - clean approach?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is a very simple (and probably dumb) question, but I can't seem to find the cleanest and best approach to it.  I have three buttons, which look fine in portrait mode.  I can also get the center one to always be centered by adding the autoResizingMasks as such:

```
[self.centerButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

However, I'm not sure of the best way to handle the left and right buttons.  See the sketch below; what I need is for them to shift just a bit, to center between the middle and left/right edges:
[image]

Sorry for the probably dumb question, as I'm sure this can be done fairly easily, either through IB or (preferably) code, but I just wanted to get thoughts on the correct and cleanest approach.  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Some additional info, I am working on an iPad, and the buttons on the bottom are actually contained in a subview at the bottom called "buttonPanel".

Per the advice of one of the answers, I added in the following code; see below.  However, I only get an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." error when adding this code, and when it lists the constraints, it only lists the ones below, so there are no other additional constraints on this view.  Is there something wrong with the code below?  Worried I'm missing something obvious here..

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.buttonPanel removeConstraint:conLeft];
    [self.buttonPanel removeConstraint:conRight];

    float paddingPortrait = 20; // pd
    float paddingLandscape = 50; // ld
    float widthOfView = 768;
    float heightOfView = 249;

    float denominatorVal = heightOfView - widthOfView;

    float leftMultiplier = (paddingLandscape - paddingPortrait) / denominatorVal;
    float rightMultiplier = (denominatorVal + paddingPortrait - paddingLandscape) / denominatorVal;
    float leftConstant = paddingPortrait - (widthOfView * leftMultiplier);
    float rightConstant = -leftConstant;

    conLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:0 toItem:self.buttonPanel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:leftMultiplier constant:leftConstant];
    conRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:0 toItem:self.buttonPanel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:rightMultiplier constant:rightConstant];
    [self.buttonPanel addConstraints:@[conRight,conLeft]];
}
```

And here is the error that is thrown:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

  "(NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8b36ce0 h=&-& v=&-- H:[UIButton:0x8874200(166)])",
"(NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8b38720 h=&-& v=&-- H:[UIImageView:0x8877880(200)])",
"(NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8b38640 h=&-& v=&-- UIImageView:0x8877880.midX == 0.165365*UIView:0x8876c00.width)",
"(NSLayoutConstraint:0x8b3a780 UIImageView:0x8877880.leading == 0.127119*UIView:0x8876c00.right - 77.6271)",
"(NSLayoutConstraint:0x8b3a6a0 UIButton:0x8874200.trailing == 0.872881*UIView:0x8876c00.right + 77.6271)",
"(NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8b36ca0 h=&-& v=&-- UIButton:0x8874200.midX == 0.848958*UIView:0x8876c00.width)"
```

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
(NSLayoutConstraint:0x8b3a6a0 UIButton:0x8874200.trailing == 0.872881*UIView:0x8876c00.right + 77.6271)

Comment: +1 for "(preferably) code". Few people nowadays make the effort coding a UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using layout constraints, you can do it with a combination of setting up the buttons in IB, and then adjusting them in code. Center you middle button and put the 2 outside ones the standard distance from the edges (which is 20 points). Make IBOutlets to the left and right constraints, and change them in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method:

```
 @implementation ViewController {
 IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *conLeft;
 IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *conRight;
}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.view.bounds.size.width > self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        conLeft.constant = 50;
        conRight.constant = 50;
    }else{
        conLeft.constant = 20;
        conRight.constant = 20;
    }
}
```

**After Edit:**

Rob is right about using constraintWithItem -- if you put in the right values for the multiplier and constant, you don't have to do anything when the view rotates, the constraint system takes care of it. So, using the same button set up that I did above, you can do it this way instead:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *conLeft;
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *conRight;
    IBOutlet UIButton *lButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *rButton;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view removeConstraint:conLeft];
    [self.view removeConstraint:conRight];
    conLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:0.1316 constant:-22.11];
    conRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:0.8684 constant: 22.11];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[conRight,conLeft]];
}
```

So I remove the left and right constraints that were made in IB (but leaving any others that were made there) and remake them in code. Notice that both buttons have their placement referenced to the right side of the view (which has a value of 320 on an iPhone) so that you can use the multiplier and constant together (the left side would have a value of 0, so the multiplier wouldn't be useful there). It takes some algebra and the basic constraint formula to figure out what those values should be. In this case (iPhone 4"), the formulas are:

for the left button:  multiplier = (ld - pd)/228

for the right button: multiplier = (228 + pd - ld)/228 (note that it equals 1-left button multiplier also)

pd is the distance from the edge in portrait (20 or standard in my example)

ld is the distance from the edge in landscape (50 in my example)

The constant value can be calculated by substituting the value of the left button multiplier into this equation:  320 * multiplier + constant = pd

Comment: Also we have to check "Use AutoLayout" in "File Inspector" to use constraints in IB. I suppose the same in "manual" way?

Comment: If using autolayout and constraints, you shouldn't be mucking around with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` at all. You would programmatically set up the left constraint of the left button and the right constraint of the right button using the `multiple` parameter of [`constraintWithItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:), and you're done.

Comment: @Rob, Why should I not "muck around" with viewWillLayoutSubviews? That method does nothing by default, so adding what I want to happen there shouldn't muck with anything, should it?

Comment: @rdelmar Apple has spent a lot of time and effort to give us a system which will re-apply constraints to move stuff around for you as the superview changes size precisely so we wouldn't have to manually intercept orientation changes and recalculate stuff. If you want to manually move stuff around in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, why bother with autolayout all (esp since you could define a constraint to achieve the nudging effect)? Having said that, autolayout is such a horrible version 1.0 implementation, that I don't blame people for doing whatever they need to in order to achieve the desired UI.

Comment: @Rob, how do you implement what you suggested? I don't understand how (or where or when) the layout constraint gets updated on a view rotation. In what method do you implement constraintWithItem? I'm also a little confused as to what the multiplier is multiplying when the second attribute is "left". What value does "left" have?

Comment: @Rob, never mind, I think I've figured it out. You need to use the right edge of the super view (rather than left whose value is 0) in order to use the multiplier.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response on this!  However, I'm a bit confused as to where the 228 comes from?  I'm actually doing this on the iPad, and I think I have it all setup correctly, but I'm continually getting an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error.  I'm guessing the 228 value needs to be different on iPad?  And the 320 should be 768 instead?  Thanks again for your help with this!

Comment: @svguerin3, Your tag said iPhone, so that's what I used for the example. The 228 is height - width (548 - 320).

Comment: It's not a problem about iPhone vs. iPad, and the expectation wasn't that you were to know that; I was just clarifying since I'm still unable to get this to work. I get the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error, regardless of what numbers I put in. I'm using 20 for pd, 50 for ld.  The two buttons I'm needing to "shift" are contained in a subview with dimensions of 768x249.  I've tried doing the calculations for multipliers and constants with those values, as well as the overall iPad dimensions (768x1004), but nothing works, it just throws that error and the buttons don't shift.

Comment: @svguerin3, it sounds like you might have other constraints that are preventing the move. You should update you question with what constraints that 768x249 view has.

Comment: No other constraints as far as I can tell.  I checked the subview's code, as well as its setup in IB, but nothing I can see that contains a constraint. :(

Comment: FYI - Edited the question to contain more info, as well as the code I added to match with this answer.

Comment: @svguerin3, I copied your code into a new project and got no warnings at all. It didn't work properly though until I changed the heightOfView value to 1004. That value is actually not the height of the view in your case (I was using the whole main view) -- it should be the width of the view when it's in landscape mode. When you get the error message you're getting, it spits out a whole lot of info, but the top of it has a couple of lines showing the constraints it can't satisfy -- maybe you should post that also. I can't figure out why it's not working for you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the question with the error message.  For reference, the left item is actually a UIImageView and the right one is a UIButton (which are the 2 elements I am needing to shift).  Thank you again for your help, and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: The problem is those NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints. As I understand it, you're only supposed to get those if you create views in code. Have you done that? If so, you need to put in a line like [myView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; for each item you create in code.

Comment: Thank you!  For reference, both UIButton and UIImageView are set in IB. This new line of code worked great for the right element (the UIButton).  However, the UIImageView (the left one), no matter what, grows larger and out of the boundaries of the containing view when I add "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO", regardless of whether I eventually set the constraint or not.  Not a big deal since it still looks ok, but I'm curious why that one's acting differently from the right one.  Is the leftMultiplier/leftConstant setup correctly in my code?  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @svguerin3, it's probably because buttons have an intrinsic content size and UIViews don't. If you want it to keep the same size, you'll have add some other constraints to it. You could either add specific size constraints, or ones that are relative to the its superview.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy Way**

You can take these buttons free on horizontal axis. In this case there will be a little bit more space between right/left button and appropriate view border in landscape then in portrait orientation.

[image]

**(Second Path)iOS6 way:**

In iOS6 you can use autolayout and constraints. It's so usefull. And you can do everything you want with it.

There are many tutorials about it. I tried to find your issue exactly but failed. I touched autolayouting [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).

Answer (score 0):

Use autoresizing masks for the other two buttons as well. For the bottom left circle set it to flexible top and flexible right. For the bottom right circle use flexible top and flexible left.

Edit - I just noticed you seem to want the outside margins to increate a bit in landscape. My solution won't do that. In fact, basic autoresizing masks can't handle that case.

Your best best is probably to implement the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the view controller and to manually set the views of the circles to suit your needs.

Comment: Agreed. It's worth noting that if he wants it nudged in a little, the standard autosizing mask does that. If you set the left and right margins of all three buttons to both be flexible in non-autolayout mode, it will increase them proportionately, and thus they'll both be nudged in a bit. You only need to resort to code (`viewWillLayoutSubviews`) it you need it to nudge in more than that.